# How to use variable name in array.indexOf in MongoDB $projection pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection like

```
   {
        "LifeTime" : 123.000,
        "Host" : "xxx.com",
    }, 
    {
        "LifeTime" : 213.000,
        "Host" : "yyy.com",
    }, 
    {
        "LifeTime" : 321.000,
        "Host" : "zzz.com",

    }
```

and a predefined array like

```
["xxx.com","yyy.com"]
```

Now I want to project using `$let` & `$cond` such that if a Host is present in the array then LifeTime will be 0 otherwise same as LifeTime.

I have tried this

```
LifeTime: {
    $let: {
    vars: {
        hostname: '$Host'
    },
    in: {
        "$cond": [
            {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "$gte": [
                            ArrayOfPredefinedHost.indexOf('$$hostname'),
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            0,
            "$LifeTime"
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

But it is not returning the expected result. I think `indexOf` is trying to find `$$hostname` instead of `xxx.com,yyy.com & zzz.com`.

How can i do this type of complex query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregation pipeline will first group the documents to allow an additional array field that contains a single host element using the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) accumulator operator. This additional field will then be used in the next **`$project`** pipeline stage in the **`$cond`** expression, taking advantage of the [**`$setIsSubset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) operator:

```
var ArrayOfPredefinedHost = ["xxx.com", "yyy.com"];
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "id": "$_id",
                "LifeTime": "$LifeTime",
                "Host": "$Host"
            },
            "HostSet": { "$addToSet": "$Host" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "LifeTime": {
                "$cond": [ { "$setIsSubset": [ "$HostSet", ArrayOfPredefinedHost ] }, "$_id.LifeTime", 0]
            },
            "Host": "$_id.Host"
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "LifeTime" : 0,
            "Host" : "zzz.com"
        }, 
        {
            "LifeTime" : 213,
            "Host" : "yyy.com"
        }, 
        {
            "LifeTime" : 123,
            "Host" : "xxx.com"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: ah! Sweet. That's Perfect, Thanks!

Comment: @AnkitSarkar No worries :-)